# SonarQube and maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

when I build my project I usually call `mvn clean install`.

Now I tried to integrate sonarqube analysis. Therefore I created a new Run Configuration in Eclipse where I execute the goal `mvn sonar:sonar` with some parameters.

Is there a way to run `sonar:sonar` within the `mvn clean install` automatially?

Comment: You can configure the plugin in your pom and add it to a phase.

Comment: Running inside the same lifecycle is indeed problematic, is `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

This should be documented in "[Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)".
It will be triggered in the build phase.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.603</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Then see "[Running sonar analysis with `mvn sonar:sonar` ignores sonar-project.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095506/6309)".
To associate it with an [existing lifecycle phase seems problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41342010/6309).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

<properties>
  <sonar.java.jdkHome>C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_202</sonar.java.jdkHome>
</properties>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
   <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.11</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.11</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.10.0.2594</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->    
 </plugin>

cmd:
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=Project1 -Dsonar.projectName=‘Project1’ -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.token=sqp_3099fc6c1bee72f7633b604dd463000764581a14
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).